# Compute value of a parallel circuit R1 || R2 || ... || Rn

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, parallel

Just a quick question:

*(If you need the photo of the exercise text to understand this question, let me know, I've tried to make it simple without the photo.)*

I was solving an electric circuit problem just turning off and on independent generators, and that's okay. This is the formula when I turn off V1:
$$ V_{r3, 2} = [(R1 || R3) / (R2 + (R1 || R3))] * V_{1} $$

If I have R1 = 10, and R3 = 10, solving R1||R3 is pretty simple, this is equal to 5 (I've halved the value of resistors).

But, my question is: if I have: R1 != R3, how can I compute R1||R3?

By reading the exercise solution, R1||R3 = 10 || 20 = 6.666, but what is the process of finding this solution?

Comment: See [Resistors in Parallel](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/res_4.html).

Comment: Parallel resistors calculation is something that is usually taught in the very 1st few lessons of a general EE course. You haven't taken it yet?

Comment: @ErnestoG yes, but this is not taught well, and professor overcomplicates stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question of notation. R1||R3 is shorthand notation of 1/((1/R1)+(1/R3))

It is simply just the parallel resistor formula.

R1||R3 = 1/((1/R1)+(1/R3))

Answer (score 0):

In general, to answer your title question:

R1 || R2 || ... || Rn = 1/(1/R1 + 1/R2 + ...  + 1/Rn)

In the specific case of only two resistors, R1 || R2 = 1/(1/R1 + 1/R2) = \$\frac {1}{(R1 + R2)/(R1\cdot R2)}\$ =  \$\frac {R1\cdot R2}{R1 + R2}\$

If the resistors are equal in value = R, n of them in parallel results in R/n resistance.

If you have a calculator with a 1/x key it's easier to calculate parallel resistances from the first formula since you only have to enter each resistance value once.